# В цикле v-for не срабатывает перебор и отображение дочерних элементов массива через индекс

Tags: vue.js

В компоненте Menu.vue цикл перебирает titles - это ОК, но не перебирает subtitles и не отображает его. Придирается к тому, что не находит параметр index. Как исправить это, чтобы цикл "видел" index и по нему рендерил элементы массива subtitles???

```
<template>
   <div>
    <ul>
      <router-link 
      :key="item.id"
      v-for="(item, index) in titles"
      tag="li"
      :to="{ path: item.id }"
      >{{ item.title }} - {{ item.index }}
      </router-link>
      <ol>
       <li v-for="(item, index) in titles[index].subtitles"> {{ item }}</li>
      </ol>
    </ul> 
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data: function(){
    return {
      titles: [
       { title: 'Javascript', id: '/js', subtitles: ['Arrays', 'Objects', 'Functions'] },
       { title: 'Vue.js', id: '/vue', subtitles: ['Arrays', 'Objects', 'Functions'] },
       { title: 'cmd', id: '/cmd', subtitles: ['Arrays', 'Objects', 'Functions'] } 
      ]
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

Полный код здесь: https://codesandbox.io/s/r151qoox5m

Comment: Мне для этого нужно весь код из модульного переделать на обычный и все компоненты в переменные засунуть, а у меня проект в том виде, как указано по ссылке.

Comment: Так я же указал - в Menue.vue участок кода с циклом.

Comment: `titles[index].subtitles` - чему равна переменная `index`?

Comment: index равна соответствующему индексному значению в массиве titles. В данном случае 0, 1 и 2.

Comment: откуда 0,1,2 - возьмется?  там даже codesandbox.io - ругается на такой подход. Если вы думаете, что туда попадает `index` из первого `v-for`, то ошибаетесь, т.к. тот цикл предназначен для  `router-link`, а этот тег уже закрыт

Comment: да, напутал я всего...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вкладываете одну итерацию в другую, при этом используете один и тот же `index`.
Нужно либо задавать уникальные названия индексам для каждой итерации (например: `i`,`j`), либо не использовать их.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in titles" :key="item.id">
        <router-link :to="{ path: item.id }">{{ item.title }} - {{ index }}</router-link>
        <ol v-if="item.subtitles.length">
          <li v-for="item in item.subtitles">{{ item }}</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так это делается примерно. Сначала `v-for` проходится по массиву основному, потом в уже в каждой итерации по массиву внутреннему. Я не знаю, что должно получиться в итоге, но то, как сделали вы, реализовать не совсем получатся, как сами видите.

```
<ol>
  <li v-for="(item, index) of titles" :key="index">
    <p v-for="(it, ind) of item.subtitles" :key="ind">{{ it }}</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```